# should I cache a 600KB xml file in memory? or is it sufficient by just using XMLTextReader?

Tags: .net

I am not sure if I should cache an xml file that my application will be using. I don't know how frequently it will be reading from the xml file. Please advice. Thank You.

Comment: reading XML is expensive (performance), so if you're hitting this data frequently, I'd vote "cache". If you're hitting in infrequently, I'd say leave it don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

Depends. If memory isn't a concern but performance is, then read in the structure using XmlReader and store it. This way it won't need to be parsed again. If it's not going to be reader frequently then don't bother. Xml parsing isn't cheap. 600KB won't break the bank on memory but you'll have to deal with caching setup, but it will be worth the performance benefits especailly if you do any transforms on it or schema validation.

if this is website then store it as a static

public static XmlReader ...

That way it's shared across all sessions.

Comment: How can I cache it? I am not doing transformations or validations on it. This file is just a data repository.  I tried to cached it with sample code below but its not cached .         //Cache XML
            xmlReader = (XmlTextReader)HttpRuntime.Cache[MAP_KEY] as XmlTextReader;

            if (xmlReader == null)
            {
                xmlReader = new XmlTextReader("C:\\Myxml.xml");

                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(MAP_KEY, xmlReader, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null);
            }

Comment: If this is web site the use a public static so it's shared across all sessions.

Answer (score 1):

This is an "it depends" answer.

1. Do you benefit from caching? Enough of a speed difference? Add enough scalability? etc.
2. Does the file change very often? This is more of a "how long to cache question.
3. Do people need instant access to changes?

I don't think you gain much with a 600kb XML file with caching. It is rather small. Unless ... you hit the same data over and over again, in which case not caching may affect scalability.

The short answer: I don't know enough about your application to give you a single answer.

Comment: Yes that is my question :-)Do I benifit from caching a 600Kb file? Yes I will hit the same data over and over again.. What do you mean by no caching may affect scalability?

Comment: If you're using it frequently, you probably do benefit. :) I found significant gains from caching a 300KB XML file because my application was using data from the file quite often. Parsing it takes longer then using it does, so if you're using it frequently reducing the parsing part will make a real difference.